# Copied and pasted Ruby code from Hubspot API but I get an HTTPUnsupportedMediaType415

Tags: ruby

I am simply trying to do an HTTP PUT request using a Ruby script, and I am literally copying and pasting 100% of the same thing from Hubspot's example. It's working in Hubspot's example, but not mine.

For example, here's the 99% full code from HubSpot API (with my API key redacted):

```
# https://rubygems.org/gems/hubspot-api-client
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

url = URI("https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/deals/4104381XXXX/associations/company/530997XXXX/deal_to_company?hapikey=XXXX")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(url)
request["accept"] = 'application/json'

response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

When initiated by hubspot, the response is an HTTP 201, but in my Ruby script it's giving me the following error:

```
=> #<Net::HTTPUnsupportedMediaType 415 Unsupported Media Type readbody=true>
```

I have tried directly copying and pasting the exact same thing, but no luck. I would copy what I'm using, but it's 100% the same code as above except for the redacted API, deal, and company IDs. I have copied and pasted HubSpot's example directly into my rails console, but I get an unsupported media type error.

I have also tried adding a body to the request, such as `request.body = "hello"` and nothing.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing a working cURL request and the ruby script via BurpSuite, I determined that the following HTTP header in the request was the culprit:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

For whatever reason, the Ruby code in the original post uses this content-type by default, even though the user doesn't specify it. Makes no sense.